# How do I prevent Conda from activating the base environment by default? Want to use oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, anaconda

I cloned this directory 'git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-$HOME/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/themes/powerlevel10k
' and afterwards, I typed in this command 'open ~/.zshrc'

But Anaconda3 is activating the base environment. So I deleted anaconda3. But I'm still getting this output after the last command:

> # >>> conda initialize >>>
> # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
> __conda_setup="$('/Users/hellme21/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
> if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
> eval "$__conda_setup"
> else
> if [ -f "/Users/hellme21/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
> . "/Users/hellme21/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
> else
> export PATH="/Users/hellme21/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
> fi
> fi
> unset __conda_setup
> # <<< conda initialize <<<

Can please somebody help me

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your `~/.zshrc` file in a text editor. You can use the command nano `~/.zshrc` to open the file in the Nano editor.
2. Look for the block of code that starts with `# >>> conda initialize >>>` and ends with `unset __conda_setup # <<< conda initialize <<<`. This is the initialization script for conda.
3. Delete this entire block of code.
4. Save the file and exit the text editor.

After making these changes, the initialization script for conda should no longer be present in your `~/.zshrc` file, and you should be able to use the Powerlevel10k theme without any interference from conda.